# Pulling in my last tweet to my website

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Since Twitter has changed its API I haven't yet coded anything that pulls in Twitter feeds.

How can I pull in my last tweet to my website and have it styled the way I want to like I used to be able to do before the change.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your website is developped in PHP, and you already have created your Twitter App, and generated the API and oAuth credentials here :
https://apps.twitter.com/

-> take a look here this is what you wanna do :
https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/index.php